# Web programming: Client-Side Change Tracking

Tags: client-side, change-tracking

I need a mechanism to detect what properties of a given `View Model` has changed on client. This is needed to set **ONLY** changed properties `Modified` to merge concurrent update of a same entity on the server.
I found `breeze` a good framework at the fist glance but I want to hear from other experienced people here.

I think the problem is not platform dependent however if you are curious I'm using `Asp.net MVC 4+` and `Entity Framework 6.0+`

Comment: `"to mitigate concurrent update of a same entity"` - I suspect there's more to this problem than you think.  Concurrency is not to be taken lightly or solved so cleverly.  For example, what if one user edits Field A on Record 1, and another user *concurrently* edits Field B on Record 1.  Are you intending to merge those updates?  Now Record 1 is in a state which *no user* saved or approved.

Comment: @David Yup, you are right. But I want to simply merge the changes.